# Edit is "handling improvement requests".. Oh really? I don't see any

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, review-queues, proposed-changes

I got a ping in my inbox, presumably because [this edit handles an improvement request of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/104195?filter-tags=r). But what was that request? I don't see it here.

[image]

Usually, I would see a yellow box at the top displaying the requests that were handled. I'm guessing this is a bug, but maybe I'm missing something here.

Comment: Any edit on a post with pending IR automatically dismisses the IR... whenever that was the intention of the editor or not.

Comment: @Braiam But I'm wondering what the IR was. Is it visible somewhere any more?

Comment: Looks to me you asked for an improvement on Oct 14th and are now asked to review the submission by @Manian.  Got the link from your profile: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/104195?filter-tags=r

Comment: @Hans Thanks. That seems to explain why I got pinged. But are you seeing what I'm seeing (above), with no actual IR being displayed?

Comment: Hmmm it does show up if you visit the old proposed change link at the bottom.

Comment: @animuson Those links are not visible to regular users.

Comment: Thanks @Adam I had just started trying to find it.

Comment: @Frank The old proposed change link mentioned above: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/104195?noredirect=1

Comment: @Frank This got missed during the conversion from the old proposed changes review process to what we have now. Jarrod's putting the IR display back in this week. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Cool, thanks for the update, @Adam .

Comment: Another http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/105542

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix for this rolled out Sunday evening.  Thanks!